# GIT_EDITOR not working with macvim

Tags: git, bash

This is what I have in my ~/.bashrc

```
export GIT_EDITOR='/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim -g '
```

When I issue

```
git commit
```

then I get a macvim editor but on the command line I see this message

```
$ git commit
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

If I use change GIT_EDITOR to use textmate then things work fine

```
export GIT_EDITOR='/usr/local/bin/mate -w'
```

I don't want to use textmate. I want to use macvim. I am using mac and use bash.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to supply the `-f` option to vim to ensure that it doesn't background itself.

Comment: This no longer works in `--patch` mode. If you edit a hunk, it opens properly. When you `:wq` from Macvim the hunk is edited and `--patch` moves on to the next hunk, but then immediately quits with `suspended (tty input)  git add -p`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by setting mvim as the default editor for git by running the following from the command line:

```
git config --global core.editor "mvim -f"
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked great for me.
`git config --global core.editor 'mvim -f --nomru -c "au VimLeave * !open -a iTerm"'`
If you are using `Terminal.app` instead of `iTerm.app` you can just switch it out.
Source: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/FAQ (though they are using the EDITOR env variable instead of the gitconfig)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if there are already other Vim windows open?

Comment: Did you try it with other windows open? It should not have any negative effects. What problem are you having?

Comment: I am unable to get this working, I understand what it should do but I get this error: `warning: core.editor has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor`

Could you help me out here please?

Comment: Well, I got it working by placing this to my ~/.zshrc `export GIT_EDITOR='mvim -f --nomru -c "au VimLeave * !open -a iTerm.app"'
`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Adding the `--noplungin` flag to vim solved it for me.