# git rebase -i presents an empty MacVim file

Tags: git, vim, macvim, interactive, rebase

I'm trying to rebase a commit. However, any time I run `git rebase -i f83eff3ffc8`, for example, a MacVim window opens, that's empty (there is no information in the file). Then once I write and close the file (even though it's empty), I get a `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/clicktocall-hotfix` message.

The file name is `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo`. I also tried running it with sudo but this didn't make a difference.

What could be the problem? I've never successfully completed a rebase.

Comment: Nothing to do with vim. Removed tag.

Comment: It looks like git is succesfully performing a "no-op" rebase. What are you trying to do? Please describe your branch structure and where the commit `f83eff` is. You might find this helpful: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch05.html

Comment: Exactly, an empty rebase -i file means you try and rebase the HEAD itself, this is not how git rebase works.

Comment: Readded vim tag as that's what's invoked by default when issuing git rebase -i.

Comment: I have this same problem, but I'm not using vim.  I'm running git from a Cygwin terminal, and I've tried setting my `core.editor` to a bunch of different editors such as notepad2 and GitExtensions, but I keep getting the empty file when I try to do an interactive rebase, and I don't know why.  notepad2 works when I do `git commit`.  I've heard that `rebase` is actually a perl script, so maybe that might have something to do with it?  I'm using git version 1.8.1.3.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with Windows vs *nix line-ending formats?

Comment: Been playing around with stuff, it might have something to do with the way paths are represented in perl and/or Cygwin, I tried interactive rebase with plain vanilla notepad, and I got the empty file in the editor, but it also said that the path was not recognized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using Macvim and needed to run mvim with the `-f` option, as documented here: [GIT_EDITOR not working with macvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737381/git-editor-not-working-with-macvim)

Comment: For reference. I had a similar problem when switching from Sublime to Atom and forgot to update git editor. This should help:

git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"

Answer (score 15):

For atom I was able to fix by adding the wait flag to gitconfig (reference https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/)

```
[core]
    editor = atom --wait
```

Comment: Since VSCode is based on Atom, the same flag works (i.e. `code --wait`)

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this as well in VS Code, and the issue was that I had forgotten the "wait" flag in my editor config.

Solved by running:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

Comment: This worked on my system as well (Mac M1)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Atom and run into this problem. I set my default editor like this:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

Now everything is working great.

TL;DR; Use Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vim on macos, and I changed the Joshua's answer to this and it worked for me too:

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not even have to look at the `git-rebase-todo` file. Vim should display a noop line and some comments. After saving that, you should get "Successfully rebased and updated ".

You are either using an old version of git, you have a broken git install or you have touched the .git folder in some way to cause it to behave this way.